# Run Azure compute emulator and storage and launch website without visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, azure

I'm developing a Windows Azure Web Role. Everything is fine, but in order to launch the site I need to run it from visual studio each and every time and let it start the emulator with the site.

What I would like to do is some how run it independently of visual studio, use visual studio to develop and compile and just refresh the site (as if I was building a regular web project and was hosting it on my local IIS).

Is this possible with the Azure emulator?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  There could be a couple of options here.  If your web site doesn't need access to the Azure role environment at all (meaning you aren't using RoleEnvironment anywhere in your code and you don't have dependent start up tasks, etc.) you can set it as the start up project and it will run under IIS (or IIS Express if you have that set) outside of the emulator.  This is just like what you are used to.  There could be some issues here if you need the actual emulated environment for some reason.  If you are connecting to the Development storage you should still be okay as long as you ensure the storage emulator is already running (which you can manually start outside of studio either with the command line, or hit the start button and start typing "Windows Azure Storage Emulator - v2.2" until you see it as a choice).  The storage emulator runs separate from the compute one and will be listening on the ports it is configured for.

The issue with not running the emulator if it is required is that you need to have the application packaged and deployed.  You can directly use the csrun command line tool to spin up a deployment in the emulator. Mike Barlow did a post on it a few months ago: "[How-to deploy application to Windows Azure Compute Emulator with CSRUN](http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/how-to-deploy-application-to-windows-azure-compute-emulator-with-csrun/)"  Note that the article has you spin up something without VS open, but it still needed to be "packaged" and put in the referenced csx directory.

You may also want to look at the new [Express Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn339018.aspx) which is supposed to be a little more stream lined, at least permissions wise, but I can't say if it is any faster or not.  I'd consider it beta currently.